# Rank based on value in list of dictonaries in Python

Tags: python

I have the following information structured as list of dictionaries:

```
tax_calc = [
{
    "comp":"Gle LTD",
    "tax":120
},
{
    "comp":"Pep LDT",
    "tax":1522
},
{
    "comp":"Leg Inc",
    "tax":246
},
{
    "comp":"Nen Inc",
    "tax":300
}]
```

What is the best way to get the name of the companies with the highest and lowest tax return (tax)?

Thank you!

Comment: `tax_calc.sort(key=lambda dct: dct["tax"])`

Comment: how do you define "best"?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do it so I'd be thankful for every approach. I'm new to Python

Comment: @hiro protagonist, the key should be "comp"?

Comment: Hi Merkera, please post the code you have made to attempt to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @hiro protagonist comment, what you need to do is

```
tax_calc = [
{
    "comp":"Gle LTD",
    "tax":120
},
{
    "comp":"Pep LDT",
    "tax":1522
},
{
    "comp":"Leg Inc",
    "tax":246
},
{
    "comp":"Nen Inc",
    "tax":300
}]

tax_calc.sort(key=lambda dct: dct["tax"])
```

This will sort your list based on the tax number for each item.

Then you just need to get the first company name and the last company name

```
lowest_tax_company = tax_calc[0]["comp"]
highest_tax_company = tax_calc[-1]["comp"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.